# Formatting number as thousand using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

`Console.log` is showing the correct result, but how can I add the same formatting to the input type while typing.

Input type is reset after every comma to zero.

1000 to 1,000

Please Help.

This code is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Enw85/1/)

```js
function numberWithCommas(number) {
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        return '';
    }

    var asString = '' + Math.abs(number),
        numberOfUpToThreeCharSubstrings = Math.ceil(asString.length / 3),
        startingLength = asString.length % 3,
        substrings = [],
        isNegative = (number < 0),
        formattedNumber,
        i;

    if (startingLength > 0) {
        substrings.push(asString.substring(0, startingLength));
    }

    for (i=startingLength; i < asString.length; i += 3) {
        substrings.push(asString.substr(i, 3));
    }

    formattedNumber = substrings.join(',');

    if (isNegative) {
        formattedNumber = '-' + formattedNumber;
    }

    document.getElementById('test').value = formattedNumber;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test" class="test" onkeypress="numberWithCommas(this.value)">
```

Comment: I guess you need use timeout around setting the element value.

Comment: when u see console,the value are printed fine but how to bring them inside input type

Comment: use `onkeyup` instead

Comment: @dandavis - input reset after every 5 digits

Comment: input is being reset because you set type to `number` but a string with commas in it is no longer a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

- Because you want commas, the type is not a number, it's a string
- Because you want to work on the input after you type, it's onkeyup not onkeypressed

I have a solution that does a regex replace for 3 characters with 3 characters PLUS a comma:

```
var x = "1234567";
x.replace(/.../g, function(e) { return e + ","; } );
// Gives: 123,456,7
```

i.e. almost the right answer, but the commas aren't in the right spot. So let's fix it up with a `String.prototype.reverse()` function:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function reformatText() {
    var x = document.getElementById('test').value;
    x = x.replace(/,/g, ""); // Strip out all commas
    x = x.reverse();
    x = x.replace(/.../g, function(e) { return e + ","; } ); // Insert new commas
    x = x.reverse();
    x = x.replace(/^,/, ""); // Remove leading comma
    document.getElementById('test').value = x;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" class="test" onkeyup="reformatText()">
```

Comment: Reworked the answer so it covers the HTML part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6cqn3uLf/
You'd need another regex to limit to numbers but this will format based on the user's locale - which may be advantageous here.

```
<input id="mytext" type="text">
```

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnformat').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
        var x = $('#btnformat').val();
 $('#btnformat').val(Number(x.replace(/,/g,'')).toLocaleString());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Enw85/1/) i need same but with keypress event.On evry key press it take the value and format digit as 1,000.

Comment: please check fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var real_num =  x.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    console.log(real_num);
    document.getElementById('test').value = real_num;
}

<input type="number" id="test" onkeypress="numberWithCommas(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is not overhead for your application then you can use 
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/