# javascript toString not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tostring

I have the **following function that is working fine on chrome and firefo**x, but ***breaks and shows NaN in IE***:

```
function (value) { 
    return value.toString().replace(/SOME REGEX/g, " ");
}
```

I am trying to get a number and format it with regex and show it. 
Value is a number, I convert it to string giving it a special format with the regex.
More precisely, I am using [this slider here](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) and the integer value is part of the translate function of this slider.
an example can be: a value of 123456 is being shown as **123 456** with a space every three digits.

what is the solution in this case?

### update

as you can see in the above slider link, I am trying to show the min/max values which are numbers with a space between every three digits, using the *translate* function of this slider.

Comment: What is `SOME REGEX`?

Comment: updated my question to clarify that point

Comment: And what is the expected result?

Comment: Have you tried adding a line before the `return` with like `console.log("value", value, "value.toString", value.toString())`?

Comment: Duplicate of [*Formatting number as thousand using only Javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868393/formatting-number-as-thousand-using-only-javascript)?

Comment: What does "not working in IE" mean in this case?

Comment: @MaxArt The question says _“breaks and shows NaN”_.

Comment: @Xufox That doesn't explain much, except maybe it hints at `value` being `NaN` right from the start. It's not `toString` that's not working.